# Openerp 7.0 server not getting started

Tags: github, odoo, openerp-7

I have downloaded fresh copy of the 7.0 branch of odoo from the github, I have changed all the necessary things like user, password, port and I tried to start the server but getting this error,

```
2015-03-12 06:47:50,735 7260 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2015-03-12 06:47:50,736 7260 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: cannot import name models
2015-03-12 06:47:50,736 7260 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/odoo_v7/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
    openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/odoo_v7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 415, in load_openerp_module
    getattr(sys.modules['openerp.addons.' + module_name], info['post_load'])()
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/odoo_v7/addons/web/http.py", line 628, in wsgi_postload
    openerp.wsgi.register_wsgi_handler(Root())
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/odoo_v7/addons/web/http.py", line 517, in __init__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/odoo_v7/addons/web/http.py", line 580, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/odoo_v7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/emipro_addons/quotation_split/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import py
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/emipro_addons/quotation_split/py/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sale_order
  File "/home/viraj/workspace/v7_development/emipro_addons/quotation_split/py/sale_order.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openerp import models, fields, api, _
ImportError: cannot import name models
```

If anyone know this please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the structure of openerp-7 has been changed, guide me if anyone knows the solution of it.

Comment: Ohhh, I got the issue, it's because there is one module I placed which was used from openerp import models, fields, api, _ which is actually of v8 code.
I have changed it according to v7 and done it.